# How to replace button with text based on the id attribute from html to ajax

Tags: ajax

I have many products and each products have buttons with different attribute IDs. On click of that button, the attribute of the button is passed to ajax function and I am able to get different attribute ID when I give them in alert message.

Now I want to replace the button with a text based on that attribute ID.

html code:

```
<button bookid='".$row['bookid']."' id='book' type='button'>Add</button>
```

My ajax code is:

```
$("body").delegate("#book","click",function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    var bid = $(this).attr('bookid');
    $.ajax({
        url : "login_action.php",
        method : "POST",
        data : {addToStore:1,bookid:bid},
        success : function(msg){
            if(msg == 0){
                alert('Already 1 product is added ');
            }else{
                $(bid).text('Added');
            }
        }
    })
})
```

The problem is I am not able to replace the button with the text "Added".

Comment: `bid` is a String, not an element; a String - so far as I'm aware - even in jQuery has no [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method.

Comment: I don't really get u, but I think u can use `#book`

Comment: David Thomas, when i try to give 'bid' within alert box, I am able to get the respective IDs. Same way how to set the text for them based on their IDS. Hope you can understand :-(

Comment: Ashik, if i give #book, then it will replace only the first div part. And if i click the button which is in 4th div tag, It doesnt effect.